# List from user input in powershell getting replaced instead of appended

Tags: list, powershell

In my script, I the user to add values to a list that I will use for the rest of the script.
I'm currently using this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,380)
$form.Padding = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Padding(20,100,20,20)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$textBox.ReadOnly = $true
$textBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$inputLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$inputLabel.Text = "Doc:"
$inputLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
$inputLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,22)
$form.Controls.Add($inputLabel)

$addDocButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$addDocButton.Text = "Add to project"
$addDocButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,23)
$addDocButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220,20)

$docs = @()
$addDocButton.Add_Click({
  $docs += $inputBox.Text
  $textBox.AppendText("Document added to project: $docs`r`n")
  $inputBox.Clear()
})
$form.Controls.Add($addDocButton)

$inputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$inputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20)
$inputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(70,20)
$form.Controls.Add($inputBox)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

but the list is getting rewritten every time I click the button.
Shouldn't the "+=" be appending the values and not rewriting it?

Comment: You need to make your $docs global: `$Global:Docs`

Answer (score 0):

If variable `$docs` is needed after the window has been closed, best define it as [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) object because that is optimized for adding and removing items as opposed to a static array.

<sup>When adding items to an array defined with `@()` using `+=`, the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt in memory, which is time and memory consuming</sup>

When an event handler scriptblock needs to address a variable defined **outside** the scriptblock, you need to scope it with `$script:`, otherwise the variable will be simply a new variable, local to the scriptblock.

```
$docs = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$addDocButton.Add_Click({
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($inputBox.Text)) {
        $str = $inputBox.Text.Trim()
        # refer to the $docs object defined OUSIDE this scriptblock with $script: scoping
        $script:docs.Add($str)
        $textBox.AppendText("Document added to project: $str`r`n")
    }
    $inputBox.Clear()
})
```